# Given set of i.i.d. RVs with distribution $f$, find distribution of orthonormal transformation

Tags: random-variables, linear-transformations, orthonormal

I have a random vector $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ of supposedly i.i.d. random variables and I can generate a histogram for one of them, giving me an estimate of its pdf.  Suppose I have an orthonormal transformation $\mathbf{U}$.  Are the components of $\mathbf{U} \mathbf{X}$ also i.i.d. with the same pdf?  Is there anything I *can* say about $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{X}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_{\mathbf {UX}}(\mathbf x)=\dfrac{1}{|\det \mathbf U|}f_{\mathbf X}(\mathbf U^{-1}\mathbf x)=f_{\mathbf X}(\mathbf U^T \mathbf x),
$$ 
where $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb R^3$.

The distribution of $\mathbf {UX}$ remains the same as the distribution of $\mathbf X$ iff the distribution of $\mathbf X$ is spherically symmetric. The distribution of vector consisting of independent r.v. is spherically symmetric iff the distribution of $X_i$ is Gaussian with zero mean.

There are a lot of links on the subject, [here's the first one](http://aurelie.boisbunon.free.fr/downloads/loisSS.pdf).